# NSString stringWithFormat syntax

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsstring, stringwithformat

In one of the sample codes by Apple, I see the following lines:

```
int digits = MAX( 0, 2 + floor( log10( newDurationSeconds)));
self.exposureDurationValueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1/%.*f", digits, 1/newDurationSeconds];
```

I am not able to understand the syntax, there are two arguments to `stringWithFormat:` but only one `%` sign. I understand it is string value of `1/newDurationSeconds` upto `N=digits` but the syntax is something I don't get.

And how do I translate it to **Swift 3**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter supplies the number of decimal digits desired and is represented by the `*`, and the second value is the number.

In **Swift**:

```
String(format: "1/%.*f", digits, 1/newDurationSeconds)
```

Note:  This capability is supplied by the *Foundation* framework.  You must `import Foundation` (or `import UIKit` or `import Cocoa`) for it to work.

You can find documentation for the format string [here (Apple's Documentation)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265) and [here (IEEE printf specification)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html).

In the second document, the `*` is explained:

> A field width, or precision, or both, may be indicated by an asterisk ( '*' ). In this case an argument of type int supplies the field width or precision.

Comment: Can you please point me to documentation of usage of * in NSString format?

Comment: @DeepakSharma: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1497275-stringwithformat?language=objc links to https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/formatSpecifiers.html which in turn links to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html. On that page: *"A field width, or precision, or both, may be indicated by an asterisk  ..."*

Comment: Thanks @MartinR.  I was getting there, but I had 3 pets demanding to be fed **immediately**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NumberFormatter instead of C style format strings; its often clearer, though longer:

```
  let newDurationSeconds = Double(10.7)
  let digits = max(0,2 + (log10(newDurationSeconds).rounded(.towardZero)))
  let formatter = NumberFormatter()
  formatter.maximumFractionDigits = Int(digits)
  let s = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: newDurationSeconds))
```